# SQLite statement to query for Recurring Calendar Events

Tags: sql, time, calendar, schedule, recurrence

I am designing a Calendar Application, which recurrence None, Daily, Weekly, Monthly & Yearly.
One of my requirements is that **"No two events should be overlapping"**
Name of the Table where I store the data

> Events

fields

> dtstart - Event StartTime
>
> dtend - Event End Time

Consider following two case,

> **Event1 15th Aug 3:00 PM - 4:00 PM  Recurrence-None**
>
> **Event2 15th Aug 2:00 PM - 5-00 PM  Recurrence-None**

In the above case, the following SQL Query works like charm

> String sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM Events WHERE dtstart AND dtend
>   BETWEEN %d AND %d";
>
> sqlQuery = String.format(sqlQuery, dtstart, dtend);

Now, Consider case two.

> **Event1 15th Aug 3:00 PM - 4:00 PM  Recurrence-Daily upto 20th Aug**
>
> **Event2 18th Aug 2:00 PM - 5-00 PM  Recurrence-None**

In case two my sqlQuery fail, since it checks the event start and end time for the same date(18th Aug). In my case, my query should show a conflicting time for 15th August.

Please help me with the SQL query, such that even recurring events are checked.

> In the events table, I store start time, end time, date of last
>   occurance and occurance type.

Database Scheme is as follows

> **Table Name : Events**
>
> **Title** | **dtstart** | **dtend**   | **repeat Type** | **last Occurrence**

Comment: Are `dtstart` and `dtend` the only fields in `Events` or do you store the recurrance and the date of last occurance as well? Do all reoccurant events have an end date or can they last for ever?

Comment: What is your recurrence data column(s) name and type?

Comment: @Bohemian recurrence data column is repeat type which takes value -1 = No Recurrence, 0 = Recurs Daily, 1 = Recurs Weekly, 2 = Recurs Monthly, 5 = Recurs Yearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to detect whether a single newly inserted (or updated) event has overlaps (**not** whether any of of the events already in the database have overlaps), correct?

If so, you could procedurally (in your client language) generate all start/end intervals `[s, e]` based on the newly inserted event's "repeat Type", and then execute the following query for each of these intervals to detect overlaps (I'm using Oracle syntax here, I'm assuming SQLite is similar):

```
-- A time interval must be either completely "to the left" or completely
-- "to the right" of the other time interval for them not to overlap.
SELECT * FROM EVENT
WHERE
    NOT(
        (:s < DTSTART AND :s < DTEND AND :e < DTSTART AND :e < DTEND)
        OR (:s > DTSTART AND :s > DTEND AND :e > DTSTART AND :e > DTEND)
    )
```

Don't expect stellar performance though (especially if your event has large number repetitions or if DTSTART/DTEND are not indexed or SQLite is unable to properly leverage that index).

For performance, you will probably be better off caching all events in memory and doing all processing client-side, which would allow you to more easily use heuristics to "short-circuit" some processing. For example:

- If two events have same "repeat Type", you can just compare their initial intervals without worrying about repetitions - if they don't initially match, they'll never match.
- If one event's "last Occurrence" is before other even't "dtstart", they can never match regardless of "repeat Type".
- Etc...

If you really want all of your processing database-side **and** you want (query) performance, you are probably looking at some kind of geospatial/multidimensional indexing and you'll need to actually store the event repetitions in the database so they can be indexed, which would probably destroy your insert performance. I'm not familiar with SQLite and whether it supports this kind of indexing...

Comment: Much of that check is redundant. This is enough: `:s < DTEND AND :e > DTSTART` (Assuming valid input and data). If any of these two conditions are false, the event does not overlap.

Comment: Yup, you are right. As long as `:s` is before `:e` and `DTSTART` is before `DTEND`, my condition "collapses" into yours.

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of a single SQL statement which does check overlapping events with recurrance, but here are some suggestions.

1. If all of your recurring events have an definite end date, you could create a table `EventInstance` consisting of `EventID`, `StartTime` and `EndTime`. Then you write `AFTER INSERT`, `AFTER UPDATE` and `AFTER DELETE` Triggers on your `Event` table to update all instances stored in `EventInstance`. Then your query can be used on the `EventInstance` table. But tbh, I don't have any experience with SQLite so I don't know whether it supports triggers.
2. Write a stored procedure in the database to check it with procedural code (again if SQLite supports it)
3. Check the overlapping events in Java code.

Comment: The requirement is such that, i don't have to create a new Table for recurrence. All the information(start time, end time, recurrence, last occurrence) are stored as a single entry in the Events table. So in my case, I need a SQL Query for doing the trick...

Answer (score 1):

It'll be quite some code. I'll outline the check for a weekly reoccurence event A, which starts before a "none" occurence event B.

1. Do your check as if both were "none".
2. If they don' overlap, add 7 days to A.dtstart and dtend.
3. Check again.
4. Repeat until a check succeeds or A.dtstart > B.dtend.

Use variants of this for daily, montly, etc. If both events are one the same occurence schedule this works too.

If they are on different ones, you need to have a second outer loop which iterates over the other interval. The stop condition can be tricky, I think it'll be something like the least common multiple of both interval sizes in days.

All this code will have to be done in your host language, which *can* be used as a stored procedure language in SQlite directly. How this is done varies on the host language.